# Procurar maior valor da linha e retornar o título da coluna de um data frame

Tags: r, data.frame, tibble

eu tenho um data frame em formato wide com 5 variáveis (`Município`, `Agropecuária`, `Indústria`, `Serviços Públicos` e `Serviços Privados`). Gostaria de criar uma sexta variável chamada de `Predominante` com o nome da coluna, ou seja, o nome do setor com o maior valor da respectiva linha.

Exemplo para linha 1: Salvar o texto "Agropecuária" na variável `Predominante` (uma vez que é o setor com o maior valor) e assim sucessivamente.

A head da tibble está logo abaixo para visualização.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  Município                  Agropecuária Indústria `Serviços Públicos` `Serviços Privados` Predominante
  <chr>                             <dbl>     <dbl>               <dbl>               <dbl> <chr>       
1 Alta Floresta D'Oeste - RO       165892     26369              155271              123512           
2 Ariquemes - RO                   163121    339667              674541             1034184           
3 Cabixi - RO                       62337      5179               42164               25171           
4 Cacoal - RO                      212493    222558              548595              971609           
5 Cerejeiras - RO                   61973     22818              109796              208728           
6 Colorado do Oeste - RO            73479     26195              105915              103454
```

Alguém tem alguma dica de como posso resolver essa questão?

Caso queiram reproduzir o código, segue abaixo:

```
## Pacotes Utilizados --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

library(sidrar)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(geobr)

## Base de Dados -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

PIB.Municipios <- get_sidra(api = '/t/5938/n6/all/v/513,517,525,6575/p/last%201/d/v513%200,v517%200,v525%200,v6575%200') %>% 
  select(Município, Variável, Valor) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Variável, values_from = Valor) %>% 
  rename(Agropecuária = `Valor adicionado bruto a preços correntes da agropecuária`) %>% 
  rename(Indústria = `Valor adicionado bruto a preços correntes da indústria`) %>% 
  rename(`Serviços Públicos` = `Valor adicionado bruto a preços correntes da administração, defesa, educação e saúde públicas e seguridade social`) %>% 
  rename(`Serviços Privados` = `Valor adicionado bruto a preços correntes dos serviços, exclusive administração, defesa, educação e saúde públicas e seguridade social`) %>% 
  mutate(Predominante = '')
```

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Esta solução é em R base. Primeiro um ciclo `apply` determina o número da coluna numérica com o maior valor em cada linha. Depois cria a nova coluna com os nomes de colunas correspondentes a esses números.

```
i <- apply(dados[-1], 1, which.max)
dados$Predominante <- names(dados)[-1][i]

dados
#                   Município Agropecuária Indústria Serviços.Públicos Serviços.Privados      Predominante
#1 Alta Floresta D'Oeste - RO       165892     26369            155271            123512      Agropecuária
#2             Ariquemes - RO       163121    339667            674541           1034184 Serviços.Privados
#3                Cabixi - RO        62337      5179             42164             25171      Agropecuária
#4                Cacoal - RO       212493    222558            548595            971609 Serviços.Privados
#5            Cerejeiras - RO        61973     22818            109796            208728 Serviços.Privados
#6     Colorado do Oeste - RO        73479     26195            105915            103454 Serviços.Públicos
```